# Prove or disprove: if $A$ is nonzero $2 \times 2$ matrix such that $A^2+A=0$, then A is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> if $A$ is nonzero $2 \times 2$ matrix such that $A^2+A=0$, then A is invertible

I really can't figure it out. I know it's true but don't know how to prove it

Comment: **Prove** is the verb, **proof** is the noun.

Comment: I changed the quadratic equation, didn't check the grammar, but you are right though.

Comment: "I know it's true..." how do you know this? You may want to be less certain of that.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ had an inverse, then

$$I = A A^{-1} = -A^2 A^{-1} = -A^{-1}$$

So we conclude that $A^{-1} = -I$, implying that $A = -I$. Can you think of a matrix $A$ satisfying the given condition that is not $-I$?

Comment: yea just the inverse of the identity, can you clarify a little more plz

Comment: @1232 The problem is reduced to asking whether there is a matrix *not* equal to $-I$ such that $A^2 + A = 0$. Can you find such a matrix?

Comment: no i cannot find one

Comment: @1232 Look harder.

Answer (score 2):

Try a diagonal matrix $A$ that's not invertible and not zero, but for which $A^2+A=0$. It might be very easy to find one.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. For example
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer becomes evident, when you view it in terms of the minimal polynomial.

Now given the above equation A^2 + A = 0, this can also be written as A(A+I) = 0

Since A is not 0, 
A either has A+I = 0, i.e, A = -I. (when A+I is the minimal polynomial of A)
  or has A(A+I) = 0 as its minimal polynomial, in this case the eigenvalues of A are 0 and 1, which implies the determinant of A = 0.
Hence its not invertible.
So either A = -I or A is not invertible.